# In ASP.NET MVC, how to make separate files for each module in a page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, template-engine

A page has several "modules" (parts of the page)
Each module has css, js, and html.
In the final page we'd like to put the css parts at the top, and the js parts at the bottom.

The masterpage has ContentPlaceHolders.
We created a ContentPlaceHolder for css, one for js and one for html.
Problem is, each one is defined with an id, so it can be "accessed" only once using `<asp:content`.
In addition, if each module is placed in a partialView(ascx file), these tags do not work (AFAIK).

We currently break apart each module, putting its css manually at the start, js at the bottom, etc.
This makes for bad coding and hard maintainability.

Is there a way to do this nicely?